# Trouble getting .* to actually match anything in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm not too sure what's going on here.  By my understanding, .* should match everything after what I've set up here except for the newline character.  If I add in a match for . or \n, it matches \n once, and ignores the rest of the string either way.

code:

```
import re
regex="(network=\{\\n\\tid=[\"|\']+identificationInformation+[\"|\'][.|\\n]*)"
contents = re.sub(regex,replacementString,contents)
print contents
```

printout:

```
information={(contents of replacementString)
}
(everything after the line containing 'id')
```

Comment: I should mention I am using re.escape(identificationInformation), not just the string as shown in the example, and have tried using .* without brackets (that was my first attempt).

Comment: Among other problems with this regex, `.` in a character class just means an actual period.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the other problems?  And I did try using .* without brackets first.  Also tried .* alone, (.*), (.)*, and others.  I'm testing this on a raspberry pi with Python 2 if it helps.

Comment: There is no `.*` in this regex. `[.]*` matches literal `.` 0 or more times.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We especially need the value of `contents` and the actual and expected output.

Comment: At a glance, `|` in a character class just means an actual vertical bar, you seem to be overmatching with the `*` bit at the end, and you should really be using raw strings for your regexes. There are probably more problems.

Comment: @DavidBinnion No, `".*"` is not an MCVE. Please read both the link and Alex's comment again.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Figured it out.
What it needed to be was:

regex="(network=\{\\n\\tid=[\"|\']+identificationInformation+[\"|\'](.|\\n)*)"

Attempting to solve it with .* wouldn't work because that wouldn't match with a newline character.
Attempting to solve it with [.]* or [.|\\n]* wouldn't work because that would make it match . as a literal as @user2357112 mentioned.
I needed to use (.|\\n)* which I must have overlooked earlier.

Also, sorry about the MCVE.  I was trying to write it but kept running into the shift-enter problem (pressing enter instead).

Comment: @DavidBinnion Then please make that the answer.

Comment: How do I do that @cwallenpoole?  This is literally the first thing I've done on here.

I also heard about endorsing or giving plus ones to helpful people, but don't know about that either.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, I found it.  No worries.

Answer (score 0):

What it needed to be was:

```
regex="(network=\{\\n\\tid=[\"|\']+identificationInformation+[\"|\'](.|\\n)*)"
```

Attempting to solve it with `.*` wouldn't work because that wouldn't match with a newline character.

Attempting to solve it with `[.]*` or `[.|\\n]*` wouldn't work because that would make it match `.` as a literal as @user2357112 mentioned.

I needed to use `(.|\\n)*` which I must have overlooked earlier.

Comment: Fyi, square brackets define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It's not just a grouping symbol; you can't use other regex operators inside it. Your entire regex uses it as a grouping symbol. E.g., `[\"|\']` is also incorrect. You simply want `[\"\']`.

Comment: Since you answered your own question with what appears to be the answer you were looking for, you should mark the question as the accepted answer.